# Resetting the MySQL database in phpMyAdmin back to default

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Is this possible? If so, can I get some help? I've looked elsewhere and it appears as though I may have to do a hard reinstall. Anyone have any better ideas?

I accidentally deleted some important databases/tables :/

Comment: Which database did you delete? A hard reinstall will only bring back the default databases, not those with your data.

Comment: Yes, I sadly deleted the default mySQL database :(